# Heteroscedascity and sample size

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

Can a small sample be cause of heteroscedascity? My guess is that it doesn't depends only on sample size, but also on sample bias or measurement error.

Answer (score 6):

Just to frame the question, let's assume the data generating process is:

$$ y_i = a + b x_i + \epsilon_i$$

- The sample size is the number of pairs $(x_i, y_i)$ you observe.
- The error terms are homoskedastic if the variance of the error term $\epsilon_i$ doesn't depend on $x_i$ (i.e. the conditional variance $var(\epsilon_i | x_i)$ equals the scalar constant $\sigma^2$). The error terms are [heteroskedastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity) if the variance is *different* for different values of $x_i$.

Sample size and heteroskedasticity are entirely different concepts.

Comment: I understand, but in small sample we could have missing observations of y given x that could cause unconstant variance of error terms?

Comment: Whether there is heteroskedasticity or not depends on the data generating process. A data generating process with heteroskedastic error terms will have heteroskedastic error terms whether you observe 1000 observations, 10 observations, 1 observation, 0 observations, it doesn't matter! Heteroskedasticity is a property of *how the data is generated.*

Sample size is how many times you see output from that data generating process.

Comment: In the classic regression model, observing (or not observing) more data does not change how the data was generated. (Caveat: in some situations, the act of collecting data can affect how the data is generated. Eg. administering tests to more students changes how much they study...  The data you collect can be entirely different than the data you don't collect.This can get quite tricky, quite complicated, and is more the topic of a whole course on selection bias in econometrics.) Anyway, the short answer is no. And if you define the data generating process carefully, it's always no.

Comment: Here, by data generating process, you mean the true regression equation, not estimated one?

Comment: @quirik Yes. I mean whatever algorithm *actually* generates the data.